# Check if the File API supply size attribute

Tags: javascript

I'd like to test if the browser supports the size attribute of the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

Is the following code could be considered as correct and reliable?

```js
var isFileSizeImplemented = typeof new Blob().size !== 'undefined';
```

Any better solution?

I'd like to determine if the browser is fully compliant, before the user try to manipulate files to upload.

I didn't find Modernizr test for this.

Comment: I wouldn't construct a `new` Blob every time I called `isFileSizeImplemented`.  Wrap the `new` in an anonymous scope and expose the `isFileSizeImplemented` in some way so that the `Blob` is cached.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier/less resource intensive to check the browser version and compare that based off of the "Browser Compatibility" list they make available?

Comment: Thank you zero298, you're right. Code modified. Now that the shape is more efficient (I hope), nothing to say about the background? :)

Comment: @zerohero, no, you should take a look at https://modernizr.com/ . More over in my case I don't mind about the resources, if the user is using a appropriate browser, then he can use the service, else he has to switch to an appropriate browser.

Comment: Will it work on my 3DS Nintendo browser?